# How to deactiviate blinking cursor on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, graphics, mouse, settings, cursor

my mouse cursor is blinking frequently when it's moved, especcially within the system settings application and similar types of windows (it
s also blinking when hovering over the "post your question" button below). Furthermore, the cursor is disappearing while I'm typing.

I remember I was able to deactiviate those things on 10.04, but I can't find (all) the option(s) on 12.04. I have already disabled the blinking cursor in system settings -> hardware -> keyboard, but it did not seem to solve the issue completely (I suspect the option does not get saved after closing the window).

Thanks in advance for any help.

edit: this is the output of lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point KT Controller (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a4)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
```

Comment: I don't think the keyboard cursor blinking has anything to do with whatever happens to the mouse cursor. Can you add the output of `lspci` to the question.

Comment: I have a similar issue with a Dell R210 II server which has an onboard graphic card G200eW WPCM450 (rev 0a). The cursor keeps blinking or completely disappear when it isn't moving. Note that it is totally random, sometimes it gets a little better after restarting Xorg :/ Tried nomodeset ... no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue before I installed the proprietary graphics drivers for my video card. Do you have any available?

Comment: No proprietary drivers available according to the application in system settings. But this machine only has an onboard graphics chip